# empty bracket initialization for struct that hold a map in cascade

Tags: pointers, go

I have the following data structure.  It a chain of a struct that each has map[string]T.  Basically I'm serializing a complex yaml file to a data structure.  I have a two version that does work but one doesn't and it not clear for me why? Based on my understand Go compiler is very smart so it supposes to figure out where object needs to be allocated.

Please consider a code below.

```
type UserData struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}
type Groups struct {
    users map[string] UserData
}
type Cluster struct {
    Group map[string] Groups
}
type Director struct {
    Cluster map[string]Cluster
}

//... I removed other add function.. Same semantic each add X function 
// check if a map is nil call make(map[string]T) add a key)
// add a key with struct (where struct hold nil map)
func (c *Cluster) AddGroup(groupName string) Group {
    if c.Group == nil {
        c.Group = make(map[string]Groups)
    }

        c.Group[groupName] = Groups {}
        group, _ := c.Group[groupName]
        return group
}

func (p *Director) AddCluster(clusterName string) Cluster {
    if p.Cluster == nil {
        p.Cluster = make(map[string]Cluster)
    }

    p.Cluster[clusterName] = Cluster{}
    cluster, _ := p.Cluster[clusterName]
    return cluster
    // does a compiler here allocate an object on the 
    // stack for Cluster {} and it goes out of a scope ? 

}
```

if a caller does something like

```
var p = Director{}
cluster := p.AddCluster("Test Cluster")
cluster.AddGroup("Test Group")
```

It doesn't work  --  First call does create a map and puts a value but the second call doesn't work.  The key is never added to the second map.

In a version that does work, I created a constructor function that does(same semantic in each method).  For example, version that does work below.  (I use here the same semantic I usually do with C++ and other languages)

```
func NewCluster() *Cluster {
    var cluster = Cluster{}
    cluster.Group = make(map[string]Groups)

    return &cluster
}

func (p *Director) AddCluster(clusterName string) {
    if p.Cluster == nil {
        p.Cluster = make(map[string]Cluster)
    }

    p.Cluster[clusterName] = *NewCluster()
}
```

I guess when you get used to one language compiler magic makes life harder :)

Comment: Just for fun, have you considered making you consider making your types something like `type UserData struct{ Username, Password string}` `type Group map[string]UserData` `type Cluster map[string]Group` `type Director map[string]Cluster`.  Then accessing the user data such as `someuser := mydirector["A"]["B"]["C"]` `someuser.Name = "jerry"` `myDirector["A"]["B"]["C"] = someuser`

Comment: Rule of thumb (particularly for young players): Choose a value or pointer receiver and stick with it. I.e. use either `Cluster` or `*Cluster` everywhere, don't mix and match.

Comment: @Peter unless you know what you're doing, and want to have interfaces apply only to pointer types vs values etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, the problem is that your `AddXXX` funcs are returning copies/values, where they should be returning pionters if you want your code to work properly. You also have to change the return type of the `AddGroup` func to `Groups` (and possibly rename the func to reflect the actual type name). I'd also avoid using `make` when a literal is shorter, and more idiomatic.

```
func (c *Cluster) AddGroup(groupName string) *Groups {
    if c.Group == nil {
        c.Group = map[string]*Groups{} // change type to use pointers
    }

    group := &Groups{} // create pointer
    c.Group[groupName] = group // assign
    return group // return
}

func (p *Director) AddCluster(clusterName string) *Cluster {
    if p.Cluster == nil {
        p.Cluster = map[string]*Cluster{} // change type
    }

    cluster := &Cluster{} // create ptr var
    p.Cluster[clusterName] = cluster
    return cluster
}
```

The problem you have has got nothing to do with where an object is allocated, but everything with what object you're working with. If you call `AddCluster`, and *aren't* returning a pointer, then the call on the returned `Cluster` object (`AddGroup`), is going to add a group to a completely different object than the one in the map you've created. What you're doing is the C/C++ equivalent of something along these lines:

```
typedef _cluster_t struct {
    int foo;
} cluster;

// and some calls like this:

int add_foo(cluster *c) {
    c->foo = 123;
    return c->foo;
}

int main ( void ) {
   cluster cl;
   int i = add_foo(&cl);
   i++;
   printf("I expect %d == %d\n", i, cl.foo);
   return 0;
}
```

Quite clearly, you're incrementing a copy of the int val assigned to `cl.foo`. You're not updating both.

---

#### Update (clarification):

A pointer var *can* be allocated on the stack or heap, that's up to the runtime to decide. Because value vs pointer returns are semantically/functionally different, however. Should the compiler make assumptions based on whatever reason, we'd all be in a world of hurt. Consider the following code in a program that heavily uses concurrency:

```
type Foo struct {
    SomeData map[string]Bar
}

func (f *Foo) AddBar(name string) Bar {
    if f.SomeData == nil {
        f.SomeData = map[string]Bar{} // this already is not thread-safe!
    }
    b := Bar{}
    f.SomeData[name] = b
    return b
}
```

If `b`, the return value, would be *"secretly"* returned as a pointer, but another routine is also updating that same value, then you'd have a race condition. What's more, there are plenty of legitimate cases where you *really* don't want a pointer:

```
type Foo struct {
    mu *sync.Mutex
    data map[string]*Bar
}
// GetBar - should return a SNAPSHOT of whatever Bar looks like at this moment
func (f *Foo) GetBar(name string) (Bar, error) {
    f.mu.Lock()
    defer f.mu.Unlock()
    if b, ok := f.data[name]; ok {
        // return COPY because it's a snapshot!
        return *b, nil
    }
    return Bar{}, ErrBarNotFound
}
```

TBH, in this kind of `GetBar` function, I'd probably return a pointer, but return it like so:

```
if b, ok := f.data[name]; ok {
    cpy := *b // create copy/snapshot
    return &cpy, nil
}
// so in case of an error, I can return nil:
return nil, ErrBarNotFound
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Good answer.

Comment: Ahh now I understand, but I had an impression it will automatically figure out that object need go on heap.  Thank you very much for an explanation.

Comment: @JohnnyBonelli: A pointer var _can_ be allocated on the stack or heap, that's up to the runtime to decide. Because value vs pointer returns are semantically/functionally different, however, the compiler isn't going to make any assumptions. I'll provide an example as to why that would be a problem, I'll update the answer

Comment: One question when you do &Cluster{} does that evaluate to allocation on the heap and return ptr ? and in my example (incorrect version), it creates struct on stack added to a map and when it goes out of the return , it goes out of the scope and garbaged collected?

Comment: You really don't get an explicit say in where any given object is allocated. True, `&Cluser` most likely will be allocated on the heap, but the only way to be certain is to dissassemble, really. In your example it doesn't go out of scope and get GC'ed, it's returned as a copy, and another copy gets stored in the map. The 2 objects aren't linked in any way. What could be happening is that the return value of `AddCluster` is allocated on the caller stack, but really, the only way to know again is: assembly

Comment: @JohnnyBonelli This really isn't an issue of stack or heap. It's about if you're passing around a copy of a struct or a copy of a pointer to some struct.

Comment: but in go idioms what version considerate better variation.  I can use construct function as I indicate it has no return.  So it just allocates something in NewX() return and adds to map or use semantics as per example ?.   Once again thank you very much for the explanation.

Comment: @JohnnyBonelli I can't say what you should do, but following Elias's advice/examples to use maps of pointers (`map[string]*Groups`) and have your 'constructors' return pointers should solve your problem and keep your code similar to the way you've already written and thought about it.

Comment: @JohnnyBonelli when it comes to which is the _better_ approach, that question is a off topic for this site. Maybe set about writing a small application that uses your current approach, and submit the code for review on the aptly named: https://codereview.stackexchange.com